# String IDs in grails - how exactly can it be done?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Can somebody show me clear, complete, 100% working way to set string-typed field as ID in grails? I've read the docs, then read all similar ranting on the web, but failed to create a working prototype.

Here is one of my attempts to make you believe I'm not just lazily waiting for somebody to do the job  )))

```
    class User {
  String login
  static hasMany = [apps : Application]

  static constraints = { 
  }

  static mapping = { 
    id generator: 'assigned', name: "login"
  }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean as 'field as login'?

Comment: What you have tried and what exact problem do you have?

Comment: @splix, ad ID of course, fixed type, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @splix, edited the question, added example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use a natural id you have to use the [findBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html) method instead of the [get](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/get.html) method as demonstrated in this test:

```
def user = new User(login: "test")
assertNotNull user.save(flush: true)

user = User.findByLogin("test")
assertNotNull user
assertEquals "test", user.login
```

Alternately you could use a single field [composite id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.5%20Composite%20Primary%20Keys) mapping:

```
class User implements Serializable {
    String login

    static hasMany = [apps: Application]

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['login']
    }
}
```

Note that [composite id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.5%20Composite%20Primary%20Keys) domain classes are required to *implement Serializable*.

The test for the [composite id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.5%20Composite%20Primary%20Keys) would be:

```
def user = new User(login: "test")
assertNotNull user.save(flush: true)

user = User.get(new User(login: "test"))
assertNotNull user
assertEquals "test", user.login
```

Comment: thanks! I see you know about grails a lot. Can you explain me, why in this case using exists method of domain class throughs error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are talking about mapping a String primary key (normally a natural key) to the primary key in a grails domain object.

This answer is derived from information found here:
http://dsommerville.blogspot.com/2009/09/mapping-natural-keys-using-gorm.html
and here:
http://gr8fanboy.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/adding-a-natural-key-to-a-database-table-using-straight-gorm/

For example, you have a table Users defined with the following schema:

```
username    varchar(40) not null pimary key,
firstname   varchar(40) not null,
lastname    varchar(40) not null
```

To do this in grails, you have to massage the definition a little.'
First, you have to map the id to the given column in your database.  With a generator "assigned"

Then, for usability, you may want to add the transient field username so that you can use user.username = .  Otherwise, I believe you'd have to access the field using id.
The getter and setter for this transient property set the appropriate "id" field, which in turn updates the database.

```
class User {
  String id
  String password
  String fullName

  static transients = ['username']

  static constraints = {
    id(unique:true,blank:false)
    password(nullable:true,maxSize:20)
    fullName(nullable:true,maxSize:20)
  }

  static mapping = {
    table 'users'
    id column: 'username', generator: 'assigned'
    version false
  }

  //
  void setUsername(String username) {
    id = username
  }

  String getUsername() {
    return id
  }
}
```

Note: Scaffolding doesn't recognize the transient field, so you'll have to work the generated controllers/views if you want your code to more closely model your db.